# Can someone explain me this "NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE" ? It's just ruining my life :(

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to make an application that can find a job for students.
I need to make a ListView inside a ListView but my **VSCode refuses to let me do it.**

IHere is the code :

```dart
IN CLASS FOR THE WIDGET :

  var offreEmploiControlerInstance = OffreEmploiControler();

IN WIDGET : 

    final List<OffreEmploiModel> offre =
        offreEmploiControlerInstance.getOffreEmploiFilteredByRevenu(100, 1500);

      Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemBuilder: (buildContextA, index) {
              return UnconstrainedBox(
                  child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
                height: 198,
                width: 290,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: const LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    end: Alignment.topLeft,
                    colors: [
                      blue,
                      darkBlue,
                    ],
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                ),
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned.fill(
                        top: 10,
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                          child: Text(
                            offre[index].title,
                            style: titleStyle,
                          ),
                        )),
                    Positioned(
                        top: 45,
                        height: 200,
                        child: Flex(
                          direction: Axis.vertical,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemBuilder: (buildContextB, ind) {
                                  return Text(
                                    '${offre[index].competences?[ind]}',
                                    style: competencesStyle,
                                  );
                                },
                                itemCount: offre[index].competences?.length,
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        )),
                    Positioned(
                        bottom: 15,
                        right: 15,
                        child: Text(
                          offre[index].entreprise,
                          style: autreTextStyle,
                        )),
                    Positioned(
                        bottom: 30,
                        left: 15,
                        child: Text(
                          '${offre[index].revenuPourEtudiant} €',
                          style: autreTextStyle,
                        )),
                    Positioned(
                        bottom: 15,
                        left: 15,
                        child: Text(
                          offre[index].dateF,
                          style: autreTextStyle,
                        ))
                  ],
                ),
              ));
            },
            itemCount: offre.length,
          )
```

I need to show this

```
"""{
      "id":2,
      "title": "Logiciel CRM",
      "descriptif": "Faire un logiciel CRM pour le fun",
      "dateD": "16/05/2022",
      "dateF": "11/09/2022",
      "lieu": "Rennes",
      "entreprise": "JeSaisPasCorp",
      "revenuPourEtudiant": 1400,
      "competences": [
        "C++",
        "Détail",
        "DB"
      ],
      "missionPrise": true,
      "fini": true,
      "referent": "John Cena"
    }
    """;
```

First ListView is for the element and second is for "competences"

And Here is the error :

```
he following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderShrinkWrappingViewport#740f9 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
RenderObject: RenderShrinkWrappingViewport#740f9 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    needs compositing
    parentData: <none> (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=200.0)
    size: MISSING
    axisDirection: down
    crossAxisDirection: right
    offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#c3781(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null, ScrollableState, AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics -> ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#98058, ScrollDirection.idle)
    child 0: RenderSliverPadding#ec235 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
        parentData: layoutOffset=None
        constraints: MISSING
        geometry: null
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero
        textDirection: ltr
        child: RenderSliverList#8d41e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
            parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
            constraints: MISSING
            geometry: null
            no children current live






════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#c2dd2 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 2009 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
Flex
main.dart:73
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#23ec6 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 2009 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
Flex
main.dart:73
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#b7e82 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 2009 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
Flex
```

I really don't know how to resolve I tried to Ctrl C Ctrl V on Google and no one explains it.
Same on stackoverflow. I saw some resolve but not explication. Rly sry for my english.

Can someone explain me why ? And how I can fix it ?

Comment: What is the parent of `Expanded`, column? And can you make it minimal with sample widget that will reproduce the same erro

Comment: It's a Column that's inside a Center.

Comment: Actually I am just thinking what exactly op trying to build

Comment: Because I have a Json File and for each element's in I need to show a view, but I need information that's inside another list in elements, I tried with for(i=0;i<....lenght;i++) but doesn't work

Comment: the current issue is on width `(0.0<=w<=Infinity,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is getting from `0.0<=w<=Infinity,` on inner ListView. You can set the width

```dart
Positioned(
    top: 45,
    height: 200,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    // width: 222, //or just
    child: Flex(
      direction: Axis.vertical,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (buildContextB, ind) {
```

But it is not necessary to have nested ListView while all are on same direction.

You can do

```dart
Positioned(
    top: 45,
    height: 200,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    // width: 222, //or just
    child: Flex(
      direction: Axis.vertical,
      children: [
for (int i = 0; i < offre[index].competences?.length??0; i++)
  Text(
    '${offre[index].competences?[i]}',
    // style: competencesStyle,
  ),
        )
      ],
    )),
```

A better way [`CustomScrollView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) with slivers.

Comment: Ok, thanks it solved the problem, but I couldn't because there was no width ?

Comment: Well yes, it needed constraints>> https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints